# I cannot get a token in a production environment in spite of good working in a sandbox environment

Tags: javascript, html, oauth, evernote, monaca

Although I have posted the below question to the evernote developer forum, that forum has been closed before I could have gotten response for my question.

I have also gotten proposal from one of evernote employees, chanatx, to check whether my key have been activated correctly. However, that forum was closed before I could get his reply.

Thus, please let me post here again.

---

I am developing evernote app in javascript.

I have a trouble regarding oauth. Although I can get a token in a sandbox environment, I cannot get it in a production environment.

I use a sample code in https://github.com/evernote/phonegap-example/blob/master/HelloWorld/www/js/index.js , which is linked from evernote web site. In a sandbox environment, I can get token, but in a production environment, I cannot. In a production environment, a screen, which I can input user name and password, is popped up. However, after inputting information, the page moves to the attached page (Sorry, that page wasn't found). Please find the attached picture.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWFbp.jpg)

What I have tried in order to move from a sandbox environment to a production environment is changing evernotehostname from "sandbox.evernote.com" to "www.evernote.com".

I am embarrassed because it does not work in a production environment in spite of good working in a sandbox environment. I have believed these two environments are completely same. However, is anything different?

I am appreciate it if you propose how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

As I've got you didn't [activate your API key for production servers.](https://dev.evernote.com/support/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have asked evernote activation and have already received Consumer Key and Consumer Secret in the production environment. However, it still does not work.